# No rule to make target guavalib_intermediates/javalib.jar needed by idegen_intermediates/javalib.jar when building AOSP

Tags: android

I am trying to build the AOSP after following the introduction given by the http://source.android.com. But i met the following problem:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=5.1.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-15.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=LMY49J
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
make: *** No rule to make target `out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/guavalib_intermediates/javalib.jar', needed by `out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/idegen_intermediates/javalib.jar'.  Stop.

#### make failed to build some targets (3 seconds) ####
```

I checkout the source to the marshmallow-cis-release branch. My java version is 1.7.0_71. At the beginning, i thought the java version is not correct for the building, so i installed another version that specified by Android official website， But failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar building problems with android builds, Using Ubuntu 16.04 try the steps below and see if it helps,

If you follow the Build Instructions on the website you are going to run into a few errors, here is how to fix them.

1. Make gcc your default compiler by opening a terminal and run "sudo -I" and enter the admin password for your computer. then add the code "sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 100"
2. run the command "nano ~/.bashrc" and at the bottom of the file add "export CXX=/usr/bin/gcc-5" than restart.
3. run the command "update-alternatives --query gcc" and you should see terminal print your version of gcc.
4. If you have trouble where make keeps failing with no error listed, try running "make efi_img -j1 -B --always-make.